# How to use Local modules in remix-run application in yarn workspaces

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, esbuild, remix.run

i have a `yarn` `workspace` `monorepo` where different packages contain reusable code. like
`@pkg/styles` ,
`@pkg/ui-components`

all of these packages are `es modules` `(import export statements)` and are used in my non ssr application built by webpack like this.

for example

```js
import { box } from '@pkg/styles'
import {Button} from '@pkg/ui-components'
```

now i need to add `remix-run` to the same monorepo and things work fine until i start importing these local packages. i get this error

```
import box from './box';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
```

if i am not wrong this is happening because `esbuild` expects all `node_modules` to be pre compiled. and simply ignores them in the transpile phase.

and i need to tell my transpiler to consider my local packages in the transpilation which is super easy to do when we are using `webpack`. but i am not sure how to do it in `remix-run` and esbuild that it uses internally. there are few issues on remix-run github but nothing seem to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of 3-feb-2022 there is no official support from remix-run for building your local packages inside a yarn workspaces monorepo. i was able to patch up esbuild config and allow local modules to be build.
[here](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/1423) is the official issue raised on remix run repo.

what i ended up doing is to patch up the remix esbuild configuration

Create `esbuild-overrides.js` in the root of the project

add following code

```js
const esbuild = require('esbuild');
const Module = require('module');

function manualExternalsPlugin() {
  return {
    name: 'manual-externals-overide',
    setup(build) {
      build.onResolve(
        {
          filter: /@YourNamespaceOrPackageName/,
        },
        (args) => {
          return {
            external: false,
            namespace: args.path,
          };
        },
      );
    },
  };
}

const originalRequire = Module.prototype.require;
const originalBuild = esbuild.build;

function build(options) {
  if (options.platform === 'node') {
    const { plugins } = options;
    const externalPlugin = plugins.find(
      (plugin) => plugin.name === 'manual-externals',
    );
    const localPlugins = plugins.filter(
      (plugin) => plugin.name !== 'manual-externals',
    );
    localPlugins.push(manualExternalsPlugin());
    localPlugins.push(externalPlugin);
    return originalBuild({
      ...options,
      plugins: localPlugins,
    });
  }
  return originalBuild({
    ...options,
  });
}

Module.prototype.require = function (id) {
  // when remix requires esbuild, it will get our modified build function from above
  if (id === 'esbuild') {
    return { ...esbuild, build };
  }
  return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

update build scripts

```json
"scrips": {
      "dev:patched": "NODE_OPTIONS='-r ./esbuild-overrides' remix dev",
     "build:patched": "NODE_OPTIONS='-r ./esbuild-overrides' remix build"
}
```

Comment: remix no supports building local modules natively.